# How to write keyboard key press action in UWP platform using C#?

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I need to write a Test cases in UWP platform. So how can i write the code for press keyboard action without key press. And how to write mouse click action in UWP platform in code behind.

Comment: [SendInput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call mouse click action you can do it simple. For example you have:

```
  private void btnStart_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
      txtBlink.Text = "la-la-la";
  }
```

call it with:

```
  btnStart_Click(btnStart, null);
```